# Identifying unknown component

Tags: identification, components

Does anyone have any idea what this SOT-223 component is?

[image]

Comment: without context, this is probably impossible to answer with certainty. Where did this IC come from? Was it in some circuit? Or a box labeld "P-Channel MOSFETs"?

Comment: Well the only thing certain is it's a 3 terminal device in SOT-223, which doesn't narrow it down much at all. A bit of multimeter testing could tell if it's a BJT or MOSFET, P or N, but besides that, usually when the code is mysterious you look at the board to know what it's supposed to do and work from that.

Comment: I suggest trying this on a universal component tester/identifier, such as: https://www.kevingittemeier.com/wow-awesome-all-in-one-electronic-component-tester-lcr-meter/

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a no-name knock-off of the TI [TLV1117-33IDCYR](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv1117.pdf), a 3.3V output semi-LDO linear regulator, similar to AMS1117.